# Is there a silent installation mode for Dia on Windows?

Tags: windows, open-source, installation, silent, dia

How can I install the open source Dia drawing software available from http://dia-installer.de silently on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dia can be installed silently by passing the /S flag:

dia-setup-0.97.2.exe /S

Note that this flag is case-sensitive. Additional command line options for the installer can be found in the NSIS documentation:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.2.1